# Mongoid not saving association to `belongs_to` association on `create_#{association}` method call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I'm experiencing some weirdness that didn't seem to be the case in ActiveRecord. Note that I'm working with a legacy database so I need to assign the foreign key on the `users` collection.

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  belongs_to :company, foreign_key: "companyId"
end

class Company
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  has_many :users
end
```

OK, that all looks good to me. But when I do the following on the console, a `Company` is created, but the `User` isn't saved with the `companyId` set on it.

```
user.create_company(name: "My cool company")
```

Instead I have to add a `#save` call on `user` like so:

```
user.create_company(name: "My cool company")
user.save
```

Shouldn't `create_company` save the `User` record?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's the intended behaviour. I haven't found in the docs (neiher mongoid not Active Record) that `user` should be saved in this case.

It will be saved in Active Record if you reverse assignment:

```
company = Company.create(name: 'My cool company')
company.users << user
```

To use this in mongoid, you need to add `:autosave` option:

> One core difference between Mongoid and Active Record from a behavior standpoint is that Mongoid does not automatically save child relations for relational associations. This is for performance reasons.  [Docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/mongoid/current/tutorials/mongoid-relations/#autosaving)

```
class Company
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  has_many :users, autosave: true
end
```

Comment: I think you may be right, but I'm not sure the intended behavior is intuitive or "correct" – in Mongoid or in Rails. I would think if I called `thing.create_owner(stuff)` that (since it's definitely writing to the DB to create the "owner", it should be writing to the database to associate that owner with "thing". Instead it just assigns the owner to the thing in the instance (memory) and is lost when the request ends unless you `save`. That feels like surprising behavior. If I want to just make an "owner", I would use `Owner.new()`. 

Comment: To me this behaviour is very reasonable. You don't call any method that suggest saving the `thing`, just the `owner`. Also I prefer to set the state of an object and the explicitly save it than to guess which method has a side effect of saving.

Comment: I think the gray area for me comes from the fact that the inverse (`owner.create_thing()`) would record the association in the database, so I was expecting a mirrored behavior. But I can see both sides.